# how can I move files with specific names from one folder to another

Tags: command-line, files

I have read this [Copying multiple specific files from one folder to another](https://askubuntu.com/questions/327282/copying-multiple-specific-files-from-one-folder-to-another) which could not help me.

I have thousands of files in `/Users/Marine/Desktop/folderGN`, some of which I want to keep and some of which I want to move.

There are several files with different names and I want to move only those that have a name containing `Protein` or `MSMS` or `PSms`.

I want to move them from

```
/Users/Marine/Desktop/folderGN
```

to

```
/Users/Marine/Descktop/myfolder
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To glob for the different names, you can use a `for` loop like so

```
for f in /Users/Marine/Descktop/folderGN/{*[Pp]rotein*,*MSMS*,*PSms*}; do echo mv -v -- "$f" /Users/Marine/Descktop/myfolder ; done
```

Remove the `echo` after testing to actually move the files.

I have copied your paths exactly (including the possible typo in `Descktop`?), but you could instead do this with relative paths:

```
cd /Users/Marine/Descktop/folderGN
for f in *[Pp]rotein* *MSMS* *PSms* ; do echo mv -v -- "$f" ../myfolder ; done
```

(remove `echo` after testing as before)

Comment: thank you so much. I cannot like it too but it solved my problem. I have one more question which I will ask soon

Comment: @LearnerAlgorithm you're welcome :D

Comment: I asked another question, I would appreciate if you could help me there too http://askubuntu.com/questions/857999/how-can-i-change-the-name-of-many-files-in-a-folder

Answer (score 2):

This is in fact very simple. If you want files with a certain letters/numbers in their name, and anywhere in the name, to be moved to some directory, just:

```
move *some_name* directory
```

Answer (score 0):

This is as simple as:

```
mv /Users/Marine/Descktop/folderGN/*protein* /Users/Marine/Descktop/myfolder/

mv /Users/Marine/Descktop/folderGN/*PSms* /Users/Marine/Descktop/myfolder/

mv /Users/Marine/Descktop/folderGN/*MSMS* /Users/Marine/Descktop/myfolder/
```

This command is case sensitive.
Notice that Descktop should most probably be Desktop, and that Users/Marine is more like a Mac setup, not a Ubuntu one.

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal window use the usual `mv` command: `mv /Users/Marine/Descktop/folderGN/*MSMS* /Users/Marine/Descktop/myfolder`

repeat for other names (i.e. PSms, etc.) respectively.