# how can I change the name of many files in a folder

Tags: command-line, files, rename

I have a folder with 1000 files.

Their name is like below

...**P1_A1** _R2....

...**P1_A2** _R2....

...**P1_A3**_R2....

which only the middle is important as highlighted

and I have a key `.txt` file in the same folder with this info

```
Sample  P   R   Col
    1   1   A   1
    2   1   A   2
    3   1   A   3
```

I want to check the `.txt` file and change the name of the file accordingly or save with with a name in another folder. for example

.._P1_A1_..

should be `sample1` because when I look at the `.txt` file , it is

```
Sample  P   R   Col
    1   1   A   1
```

for the 
.._P1_A2_..

should be `sample2` because when I look at the `.txt` file , it is

```
Sample  P   R   Col
    2   1   A   2
```

Comment: Could you give an example of what to full filename should be after rename? What if there is more than one file that should be `sample1` given these criteria?

Comment: @Zanna we dont have any more file that should be sample1, each sample is unique however, would be great to check that too and if there is any, we can mention that this file seems to be similar (for manual check). I gave an example full name above

Comment: and after rename, what would you like the full filename to be?

Comment: @Zanna Sample1, Sample2, Sample3 etc . it gets the name based on that xls file.

Comment: @Jacob Vlijm Yes sure, I can covert it to .txt is this fine?

Comment: yes that is much better... maybe you should do that and edit your question?

Comment: @Bruni I did not want to. sorry to take your time

Comment: Why did you remove the example from your question? I still don't understand what you want exactly. Can you please provide a *short but complete* example with a few original file names, their respective target file names and the text file that governs the relation between the two?

Answer (score 4):

If we can safely assume that all your names are unique, I mean that there is only one file whose name contains `_P1_A1`, only one with `_P1_A2` etc, you can do this:

```
$ awk 'NR>1{print "mv *_P"$2"_"$3$4"* sample"$1}' key.txt 
mv *_P1_A1* sample1
mv *_P1_A2* sample2
mv *_P1_A3* sample3
```

Awk reads its input line by line and splits it into fields on whitespace. So the first field is `$1`, the second `$2` etc. Here, we're processing the keys file and printing the correct `mv` command by building it from the file's fields.

If you are sure the `mv` commands printed are correct, you can run them with:

```
awk 'NR>1{system("mv *_P"$2"_"$3$4"* sample"$1)}' key.txt
```

Comment: @LearnerAlgorithm i) no, it is most certainly not the same thing! That's the sort of thing you should mention in the question. Mac uses a different version of `awk`. And this is a site about *Ubuntu*, not OSX, so I don't understand why you would ask here. ii) The first command isn't supposed to do anything, it will just print out a list of commands. The *second* command runs them. This should work for OSX as well, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @LearnerAlgorithm no it won't. The format is the same. It just creates a text file with no extension. I have no idea how OSX deals with extensions, apparently it thinks they're executable. That's yet another reason why *you should ask this on a site where OSX is on topic*. You can try [unix.se] (but clarify that you're using OSX!) or [apple.se], or even [su].

Comment: @LearnerAlgorithm As I said in my first comment, the awk version on OSX is different. The default on Linux systems is GNU awk and the one on OSX is BSD awk. In any case, if it's not printing anything, your key file is not called `keys.txt`, or it doesn't have the format you show in your question or something like that. However, and I hope for the last time, I can't help you because OSX is off topic here and I just don't know enough about it. Please go to one of the other sites I mentioned where you will be able to get the help you need.

Comment: ♦ your solution is applicable. one question and I accept your answer. The file generate new files without any format. my question is that how can I make them to `.txt` manually ?

Comment: @LearnerAlgorithm please take this to a place where it is on topic and people can  help you. I have absolutely no idea what you mean. This creates text files, they just don't have an extension. If OSX needs something special, you will have to talk to OSX people. I don't know.